# Android Facebook native app not getting user email and birthday even with permissions set and correct information in fields

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I'm trying to get the user email and birthday (using a Me request). My app has email and user_birthday permissions and the fb account i'm using has an email and a birthday set.

When I try using the 'Graph API Explorer' (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) using the user access_token with 'fields=id,email,birthday' all I get is the id.

Can anybody advice me on this please.

Here is my code:

```
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
        // callback when session changes state
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {
                // make request to the /me API
                Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                    // callback after Graph API response with user object
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        if (user != null) {
                            // here I check the infos I got.
                            Log.d("some tag", user.getInnerJSONObject().toString()); // it shows only the id, no email or birthday.

                            if (Session.getActiveSession() != null) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "Log out from FB");
                                Session.getActiveSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                // set params.
                request.getParameters().putString("fields", "id,email,birthday");
                // execute request.
                request.executeAsync();
                Log.d(TAG, request.toString());
            }

            if (exception != null) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally changed the approach using the OpenRequest instead of getMeRequest:

Here is my code:

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
    Logger.d(TAG, "Start FB session");
    // check if a session exists.
    Session currentSession = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (currentSession == null || currentSession.getState().isClosed()) {
        // create a new session.
        Session session = new Session.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();
        // set it a the active session.
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        // keep a variable link to session.
        currentSession = session;
    }
    // if a session is already open then issue a request using the available
    // session. Otherwise ask for user credentials.
    if (currentSession.isOpened()) {
        // The user is logged in.
        Logger.e(TAG, "User is logged in.");
        Session.getActiveSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation();
        Logger.i(TAG, "Session closed an token information cleared.");

        // get user data here with no extra call.
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
            @Override
            public void call(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                if (session.isOpened()) {
                    Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                            if (user != null) {
                                Logger.i(TAG, "User:" + user.getInnerJSONObject());
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        // Ask for username and password
        OpenRequest op = new Session.OpenRequest((Activity) this);
        // don't use SSO.
        op.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
        // no callback needed.
        op.setCallback(null);
        // set permissions.
        List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
        permissions.add("email");
        permissions.add("user_birthday");
        op.setPermissions(permissions);
        // open session for read.
        currentSession.openForRead(op);
        Logger.d(TAG, "Session open for read request issued.");
    }
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Logger.d(TAG, "Request code is: " + requestCode);
    Logger.d(TAG, "Result code is: " + resultCode);
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (Session.getActiveSession() != null)
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Session currentSession = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (currentSession == null || currentSession.getState().isClosed()) {
        Session session = new Session.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        currentSession = session;
    }

    if (currentSession.isOpened()) {
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
            @Override
            public void call(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                if (session.isOpened()) {
                    Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                            if (user != null) {
                                Logger.i(TAG, "User:" + user.getInnerJSONObject());
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using **Request.GraphUserCallback()**, its best to use it in **MAIN UI THREAD**

```
Session s = Session.getActiveSession();

    if(s!=null)
    {
     Request.executeMeRequestAsync(s,new Request.GraphUserCallback() 
     {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) 
        {


            if(user!=null)
            {
                 try {

                    String fbid=null;
                    String birthday=null;
                    fbid=user.getId();
                    birthday=user.getBirthday();


                } catch (JSONException e1) {

                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }



            }

        }
     });
    }
```

Comment: Hi Aditya, how does this answer my question?

Comment: what i got from your question is that you are trying to get the email and birthday of the person logged in from your app ,so this will give you a json object of user asynchronously...from that object you can get the email and birthday as well as loction, profile url, etc by the  code i have typed

Comment: The problem seems to be somewhere else. In fact I already put this line of code to see the whole JSON object: 
Log.d("some tag", user.getInnerJSONObject().toString());

The problem is that there is no email nor birthday in the first place.

It looks like the app is not granted to get those fields even with the right settings and with the field list set in the request.

The problem may be because of somthing I don't know: may be because the app needs more settings? or because it has to be an on-prod not on-stage app?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this also before the Request.executeMeRequestAsync(...){...}

```
        List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();

        List<String> permissionsBirthday = new ArrayList<String>();
        permissionsBirthday.add("user_birthday");

        if (!isSubsetOf(permissionsBirthday, permissions)) {
            pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
            Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, permissionsBirthday);

            if (setPermissions(session, newPermissionsRequest))
                return;
        }
```

the method isSubsetOf();

```
private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset, Collection<String> superset) {
    for (String string : subset) {
        if (!superset.contains(string)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me hope you find it useful. This retrieves the user email in 3 different ways and also logs it

```
     try{       
    //  new Read().execute("Facebook"); 
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

              // callback when session changes state
              @Override
              public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                if (session.isOpened()) {

                  // make request to the /me API
                  Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                    // callback after Graph API response with user object
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                      if (user != null) {
                      //  TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                       // welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");

                        Log.d("useremai", (String) user.getProperty("email"));

                    Log.d("USER",  user.getInnerJSONObject().toString()); 
                    JSONObject details = user.getInnerJSONObject();
                    useremail = details.optString("email");
                    Log.d("name", user.getName());
                    Log.d("email", useremail);

                      }
                    }
                  });
                }
              }
            });
        }catch(NoClassDefFoundError e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

if you have object of user than do below:

```
if (user != null) {
 String UserId = user.getId();
try {
Log.i("Birthdate", ""+user.getInnerJSONObject().getString("birthday"));
} catch (JSONException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```